# Is there a way to embed a constant in a struct in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In a perfect world, I would be able to scope a localparam to the inside of a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  logic [10:0] mantissa;
  localparam exponent = -10;
} my_fixed_point_type;
```

But alas, this is not legal SystemVerilog.  I've investigated using const ints (illegal), enums (not scoped to the struct, and requires "storage").

I might consider just embedding an int into the struct, and trust the synthesis tool to notice the values are only ever initialized, and strip them away, but some synthesis tools are just as likely to ignore initialization.

The only approach I've found so far that actually words is this abomination:

```
typedef struct {
  logic [10:0] mantissa;
  logic [25:0] _hidden;
} my_fixed_point_type;

`define FP_EXPONENT(var) $bits(var._hidden)
```

Since `_hidden` is never read from, I have high confidence that it will get stripped out at elaboration time, while the bit width of `_hidden` can be used to hide an (unsigned) integer constant.  Ugly!

Surely there must be a better way to scope a constant to a struct in a way that is preserved in synthesis, but doesn't take up any actual bits.  Or, do I have to take this up with the SystemVerilog 2016 committee?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you can't just use a module wide param. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to build a fixed point library in systemverilog where the exponents are treated as constants and compiled away by the synthesizer.  A module-wide param won't work, I need a constant that is scoped to a typedef.

Comment: The more I find questions and comments like this about SystemVerilog the more respect I have for VHDL.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you could do, but without knowing why you are trying to do this, it is difficult to recommend a good solution. Here are a few suggestions:

You can define an initial value to a typedef

```
typedef struct {
  logic [10:0] mantissa;
  int exponent = -10;
} my_fixed_point_type;
```

or use an anonymous enumerated type to prevent any other value ever being assigned to it

```
   typedef struct {
      logic [10:0] mantissa;
      enum {value=-10} exponent = value;
    } my_fixed_point_type;
```

or us a continuous assignment to the variable declared with this type

```
   typedef struct {
      logic [10:0] mantissa;
      int exponent;
    } my_fixed_point_type; 

my_fixed_point_type fpv;
assign fpv.exponent = -10;
```

Comment: I'll try this, and see if the synthesis tools optimize out the constants the way I hope they will.  If not, I'll complain to the tool vendors.

Answer (score 0):

`_hidden` can be made signed with `logic signed [25:0] _hidden;`

It can be made a semi-constant with `always_comb var._hidden = -10;`
`assign` could also work but unlike `always_comb` simulators are not required to give errors with multiple drivers.

An alternative is to use use an `interface` instead of a struct, where you can use `const` or parameters (even functions).

I'm not sure how well a synthesizer will optimize either; you'll need to experiment. My guess is an `interface` with parameters will strip away the unused signals better then with a struct.

Comment: Hi Greg -- thanks for the response, but you misunderstood the ugly hack -- I was using the bit width of _hidden to encode a constant, not the contents of _hidden.  I agree, it's hideous, and it would be better to just put the exponent into the struct, as long as I can feel secure that the synthesis tools will optimize it away.

Answer (score 0):

I just started to build a fixed point library as well and wanted to use a structure to hold the [full, integer and fractional] width of signals. I'm not even trying to do anything fancy, I just wanted to collect the parameters in a structure so it's easy to have access to them. Unfortunately no matter what I do the tools complain cause they think the structure content aren't constant - even if I only ever assign once.

For example:

```
typedef struct { int w, i, q; } fxpt;
fxpt dw = '{16, 1, 15}; 
wire signed [dw.w-1:0] din;
```

Or even if I would accept to have different structures for each signal so it's obvious everything is constant:

```
typedef struct { int w=18, i=1, q=17; }  dw_constant;
dw_constant dw; 
wire signed [dw.w-1:0] din;
```

I'm now reverting back to just having parameters directly in the code, such as:

```
parameter integer dw[0:2] = '{16, 1, 15};
wire signed [dw[0]-1:0] din;
```

Note that I haven't accessed the .i and .q parameter in the code snippet so it might look a bit useless, but when doing multiplication/addition those fields are important to have.